# How the server side does know that the client browser was closed and so the session will be invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

I am wondering how session does work?
 If I have:

```
Session["Mysession"]="1";
```

How the server side does know that the client browser was closed and so the session will be invalid?

How such session is created in the server side? What is the mechanism?

Comment: Alternatively, google "how do browser sessions work" -- you might actually find a bunch of info there that'll help get you started.

Comment: You might want to look at the explanation provided at this link. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work