# Http protocol mechanisms and objects

Tags: http

I want to better my understanding behind the mechanisms of the Http protocol from a web application dev's perspective. I want to clear my confusion about what objects are involved such as the session object and the request object and when are they generated and terminated and what attributes of them we would commonly use during a web application. At the expense of not making much sense.. I won't say too much more. I just wish to be pointed to a good source of knowledge on this whether it be a book/video/web page/or a detailed response to this post. Thanks kindly.

Comment: FYI, Stack Overflow is typically focused on answering specific questions or problems. See the [help docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). See #6 on that page, specifically. You'll get some heat from people about this post.

Comment: I understand. Nevertheless, I wish to become a better developer so that I don't flood SO with questions that are not well researched. But, you are right and I have taken a risk but only because I am in the noble pursuit of knowledge.

Comment: Still, check out this Stack Exchange site for Webmasters, may be a better place for this type of question - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't know why I didn't think about posting there. I was aware of it but never used it so that's why it wasn't in my mind. Thanks. I still feel like posting it there but I do not wish to get marked for duplication. Perhaps I will re-word and re-post. Thanks for your good guidance both with subject and SO etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this for HTTP and REST.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340)

[Here's a good place to start for sessions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work)

[Wikipedia is a really good source for all HTTP topics as well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science))