# How do sessions work in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know how sessions work in Ruby on Rails.

I already now that I can save a session with `session[:user_id] = @user.id` and retrieve it with `session[:user_id]`.

Thus, does Rails save the session to cookie store, cache store, or database store?

Comment: Session is stored in cookies by default. But you can change it to cache or database if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request a webpage, the server can set a cookie when it responds back. You can read this article, it will clear you concept about sessions. http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/03/17/how-rails-sessions-work/

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are kept serverside. It's saved on the webserver itself. This can be in a file/memory/database. The ID of that session is saved in a cookie on the user his browser to associate the user with the correct session.

More information can be found here:

[What are sessions? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work)