# How to invalidate all sessions after user log out in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I am new to Rails and I am following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, so my code is mostly borrowed from there. Here is the scenario:

I log onto my site using `Computer A`. Then I log onto the site using the same user id using `Computer B`. When I log out of the site using `Computer A`, `Computer B` remains logged in and can still perform actions. For security reasons, I would like `Computer B` to be forced to login again when `Computer A` has logged out. Is there an easy way to invalidate all sessions for a given user upon log out? If you have some sample code that would be very much appreciated.

I also read that it is best practice to use reset_session on log out. However, I had trouble determining whether you should use `reset_session` before or after logging out the user?

This is from my Sessions Controller:

```
  def destroy

    log_out if logged_in?

     # Reset session to prevent session fixation vulnerability
    reset_session

    flash[:info] = "You are now logged out"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

This is from my Sessions Helper:

```
  # Forgets a persistent session
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work as they have to.

Session has depends on browser.if logged in one PC then your session retain on same browser that you currently working. And if you logged in with another PC then your browser create another session for you.

You can try this scenario with well known site like google and Facebook.

Please refer below link.

[What are sessions? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work)

And if you trying to destroy all session in single machine you can try.

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could go about this is to set a flag on your user model, let's call it `active` or `status`, which would be a boolean column on your database. When the user signs out, you set the active column to `false`. Now, in your `current_user` method, in your controller, you just have to check if the user is `active`, if not clear the session.

Here's a little snippet I could scribble for this:

```
class User
 # you should add an active or status column through a migration
 # enum status: {true => :active, false => :inactive} # largely personal preference for enums, you could define other helper methods without needing the enums
end

# x_controller
def log_out
  ...
  user.inactive!
  ...
end


def current_user
  if @current_user ||= User.active.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
   # the user is active continue
   @current_user
  else
   # the user is not active clear the session
   session.clear
  end
end
```

Not tried the code before, but this is a way I think you could accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @oreoluwa's answer, this worked for me for soft-deleting accounts after sanitizing PII:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD `is_deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :require_login

  # ...

  def require_login
    if not logged_in?
      return redirect_to welcome_path
    end

    if current_user != nil and current_user.is_deleted
      session.destroy
      return redirect_to welcome_path
    end
  end

  # ...

end
```