# Rails & Devise using POST request for sign out. How can I change this to a DELETE request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, devise, http-post, http-delete

I'm using Rails 6.0.3.4, Devise 4.7.3 for authentication and testing my app on Google Chrome. I have the application containerised using Docker and Docker Compose and I'm using PostgreSQL for the database, ElasticSearch for search and NGINX for the web server.

I can Log In successfully. However when I try to Log Out by clicking on the Log Out button, it doesn't Log Out and only redirects to the home page.

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'nav-link' %>
```

The NGINX server is showing a POST request rather than a DELETE request when trying to Log Out and I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
37.228.235.151 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:50:12 +0000] "POST /users/sign_out HTTP/1.1" 302 97 "https://myapp.ie/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

When I run rake routes, it shows destroy_user_session as:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
```

My devise.rb initializer has:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

My Devise controllers are all standard (I haven't edited them).

Here's my Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  
    protect_from_forgery prepend: true

    # To enable sign in to function correctly.
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def index
        
    end
    
    protected

    # Restrict parameters for sign up input.
    def configure_permitted_parameters
        added_attrs = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :encrypted_password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: added_attrs)
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: added_attrs)
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: added_attrs)
    end

end
```

Here's my Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest" crossorigin="use-credentials">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ff8a00">
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton--color" content="#ff8a00">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Text+Me+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body id="<%= controller.controller_name %>" class="<%= controller.action_name %> <%= "show-sidebar" if @show_sidebar.present? %>">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <% if @show_sidebar.nil? %>
        <header>
          <%= render "layouts/nav/public" %>
        </header>
        <%= yield %>
      <% else %>
        <%= render "layouts/nav/dashboard" %>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <%= render "layouts/nav/sidebar" %>
            <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4 mt-4">
              <%= yield %>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

    <%= render "layouts/footer" %>

    <div id="notifications"><%= notice %></div>

    <!-- PWA Step 1 - Registration -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
          // Registration was successful
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }, function(err) {
          // registration failed :(
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      });
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.9.0/feather.min.js"></script>
    <script>feather.replace()</script>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag "counter" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the part of the view that displays the Log In / Log Out link.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="right-nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-item">
      <% if notice %>
        <p class="nav-link"><%= notice %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if alert %>
        <p class="nav-link"><%= alert %></p>
      <% end %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <strong class="nav-link"><p><%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %></p></strong>
      <% end %>
      </li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <strong><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'nav-link' %></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <strong><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'nav-link' %></strong>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <strong><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, :class => 'nav-link' %></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <strong><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'nav-link'  %></strong>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** Don't worry. Its perfectly fine.

HTML forms can only send [GET and POST requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). When you use `link_to ... method: :delete` with [Rails UJS](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-method) or just plain old forms with `button_to ... method: :delete` a POST request is used. While modern browsers [will let you send DELETE and PATCH requests with XHR requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers) this does not apply to Rails UJS as the [data-method handler](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1536a2bddbd4b775dbc1916841c137140a29d71a/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/method.coffee#L1) actually creates a hidden form element and submits it.

[Rack](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) (the Ruby CGI that Rails is built on top of) gets around this limitation by using a special parameter called `_method` which will make POST requests appear to be DELETE, PUT, PATCH etc. You might have noticed that strange hidden input in the output of`form_for/form_with`. You can also use the `HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE` header. See [Rack::MethodOverride](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/a05f8d56f9ac4da14dddb8f312a3b43644f73397/lib/rack/method_override.rb) which is the middleware that transforms the request before it reaches your Rails application.

Of course NGINX knows nothing about Rack's shenanigans and its logs will just show this as regular POST request. The same applies if you use the inspector in your browser to check the traffic.

But if you check the Rails logs you can see by the time the request makes it down the middleware stack to your Rails app Rails will think it was a DELETE request all along.

Comment: Thanks @max for the detailed answer, this is a great help. This gives me a better understanding of what's going on with Rails behind the scenes. It's good to rule this out and narrow down the list of possibilities. My issue must be related to caching or cookies as I've posted in a separate question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765439/how-can-i-delete-the-myapp-session-cookie-in-google-chrome-storage-using-a-cont?noredirect=1#comment116277166_65765439).

Answer (score 2):

In your initializer/devise.rb, try to replace **delete** with **get** on *config.sign_out_via = :delete*

Comment: This really just lets you sign out without using `method: :destroy` and is kind of hacky as GET requests are stored in the browsers history. I doubt there really is an issue here in the first place and its really just confusion over how Rack does the extended set of HTTP methods.

Comment: Thanks Zakir for the suggestion although I agree with Max, I would like to keep to the recommended method rather than work around it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that Rails doesn't do a real DELETE request when using a link_to with `method: :delete`. Check the rails-ujs code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ad3a47759e67a411f3534309cdd704f12f6930a7#diff-d9f2caa2a91064bb77ada650abdc7085044dffb4e4e35715e8ac64b1c72a0d69R16-R25

It creates a form with method POST and a hidden field `_method`. Nginx will see a POST request but rails knows how to read it as a DELETE request.

What do you see on the Rails logs? do you get the request log in the console?

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod. I'm looking at the console, the NGINX server showed "POST /users/sign_out HTTP/1.1" .