# What does the 3rd line of code from the below snippet does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  def create
    chef = Chef.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if chef && chef.authenticate(params[:password])
      **session[:chef_id] = chef.id**
      flash[:success] = "You logged In"
      redirect_to recipes_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Check your email or password"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

What does

```
session[:chef_id] = chef.id
```

do? Is that `session[:chef_id]` a kind of variable or something? To which the id of a chef is assigned? Can I use some other name there?

Answer (score 0):

`session[:chef_id] = :foo` stores `chef_id` key in session with value of `:foo`.
So you can fetch assigned `:foo` value later by calling `session[:chef_id]`.

In your code it is assigned to id of chef who has email equals to `params[:email]`.
You can name `:chef_id` whatever your like but I think it is pretty normal name.

Answer (score 0):

That's storing the chef_id in the `session`, which is a way of persisting data accross multiple requests. It's not specific to Rails, as the session is also available in all web applications. You could read more on the Rails session [here](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) and more on web sessions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804387/3893710)

Comment: So @oreouluwa is that a part of convention? Can I use 
session[:chef] = chef.id 
Will that work?

Comment: yes, the key doesn't really matter, as long as it doesn't affect other parts of your application. For example, somewhere you may be doing `Chef.find(session[:chef_id])`, in which case you have to change to `Chef.find(session[:chef])`. However, for clarity, since it's storing the `chef_id` not the `chef` object itself, I'd advise that you leave it as `chef_id`

Comment: Yea got it ! Thank you !