# Redirect to another controler from mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The question is if I can redirect from a MVC web App1 to a controller residing in a MVC web App2?

Using the same user credentials from MVC web App1 passed to mvc web App2

Regards, Jorge

Comment: What is authentication type? Is it possible to use target URL?

Comment: in web.config I have Authentication=none

Comment: Why do you neet to send credentials while anonymous authentication is enabled?

Comment: Because I have my custom authentication methods, I validate User/passs against my own user database using Owin mvc. I create a simple mvc app using the template authentication methods, I changed this to validate against this own database exluding tables like Asp.Users that come by default with entity framework. So I have to Authenticate in this site and then redirect to another action/ controller that resides in other site that implements the same authentication policies.

Comment: Did you try to use cookies? You could send a cookie with some public key from first app and read this in another after redirection. See also [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804387/7914637) about sessions.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible with simple logic you just pass data into query string.
e.g.

`<a href="application-2/ControllerName/userName/password"> Move To Next App</a>`

or you may use 

`<a href="application-2/ControllerName?username=Value&Password=Value">Move To Next App"</a>`
if you don't want to show your password use some encryption to encode username password

Comment: It is not good idea to pass login and password via query string!

Comment: in the current case you will be need to send private (secret) data **from server to client** to do redirect. This  is wrong.