# Authorization and authentication in nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, jwt

how the authorization token that is sent back after a user is authenticated is stored in browser and can be used for authorization in the same api for other routes until the token is deleted from the user's database after he logs off?

I used the postman for same. And there in the  Headers section i got the authorization token as a response header. But how does this all work in a real login page in the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are sessions? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing the token in browser you can use cookie or browser web storage (localStorage/sessionStorage). see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for browser web storage. For those routes which need authorization you should send back the token in a header or cookie. this blog [post](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) may help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Some intro,

The Authorization token is JWT usually and is created with some secret key at the server, the library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken is used mostly in NodeJs. One can use different strategies using Passport JS to make it more secure and open for 3rd party integration (like Google, FB etc).

Now your question,

When the user initially logs into the system using his valid credentials, the server generate a JWT token with **secret key** and sends it in the response header. The client side (browser) saves this token in the cookie or local storage, and for the next request sends this token in the request header. The server has the secret key and can verify the token's validation and can proceed or decline the request.

One should ideally use a token that expires in 1 hour (depends on use case) or so and not use non-expiring or long expiry tokens for security reasons.

This is roughly how it works, please let me know if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can check this sample OAuth2 based on oauth2-server you can find the repo here: https://github.com/gerardabsi/NodeJS-OAuth2