# Making sense of "Storage" in a browser

Tags: cookies, storage

In this post [about sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work), they basically say a session is a way the server has to identify a client (in subsequent requests).

The process consist in giving the client a **cookie,** that's the id. The client sends a request, the server does something like `Session[cookie] --> details`.

Some NodeJS/Express servers can create a session on connection, and set the loggin to `true` after successful authentication. Following the previous paragraph, we could do `Session[cookie].loggedIn==true`, then allow something.

I can see this either persistent or expiring cookies in the browser "storage" in the console.

But where in the server, and where on my machine is stored this data? Would a persistent cookie persist not only browser shutdown but also PC restart?

Comment: I was going to attempt to write a response to this, but you have multiple complex questions here that are each a bit too in depth to cover as a group.  Security is a major factor in the use and implementation of sessions, and just glossing over the raw basics would, at best, leave you with more questions;  at worst, leave you not understanding all the security implications involved.

Comment: Hi @Claies I appreciate the comment. Indeed I'm rather confused, but I want to be a good developer and understand this stuff. What do you think would be a more scoped, accessible way to reformulate? I know a bit about symmetric and asym. encryption. I'm just implementing a log in, without emails (so hashing and salt is not important in this simple project).

Comment: Also, my understading is more or less on this level https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/auth/index.js

Comment: well when I refer to security, I'm more referring to things like [Session poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_poisoning), or [Session Fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), or similar issues related to session storage.  It's easy to say that it's possible to do something, much harder to explain why you shouldn't.